# Overlaying a vertical line on top of a bar graph

Tags: stata

I am trying to plot in Stata a bar graph over different groups of `x`-values:

```
graph bar characteristics, over(xgroup)
```

Is there a way to easily overlay a vertical bar at a `x`-value of my choice?

Answer (score 2):

The `graph bar` command is notorious for its inflexibility.

Using `twoway bar` instead with the `xline()` option will easily produce the
desired output:

```
sysuse auto, clear
twoway bar price rep78, barwidth(0.2) xline(2.5)
```

[image]

Note that in Stata jargon this overlaid line is called a *reference line*.

Comment: The example is a vehicle for the answer showing use of `xline()`, which is more than fine. Just to explain to anyone puzzled about what the graph shows: when two or more values exist for the _y_ axis variable, as is the case here, bars are superimposed. The final result shows the _maximum_ price (in this case) for each category on the _x_ axis.